# Base Pair Map - moving for argv[i] to integer or char as input

Tags: c++, argv

Trying to keep this simple, I am defining some base pair maps like so:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])

    {

        std::string s1;
        s1 = argv[1]; //<-- copy argument to a string type to use string iterator
        std::vector<int> args_vector;

        for (char c : s1) 

            {
                args_vector.push_back(static_cast<int>(c - 48)); // convert char to integer and save it in vector
            }

        for (int i : args_vector)

            {

                typedef std::map<string, int> BasePairMap;
                BasePairMap m;

                m["0"] = 48;
                m["1"] = 49;
                m["2"] = 50;
                m["3"] = 51;
                m["4"] = 52;


                char ii = static_cast<char>(i);

                int in_arg = m[argv[i]];    //works
                int in_arg = m[ii];         //does not work

            }

            return 0

    }
```

In an earlier version of this project I was passing in multiple command line arguments as so:

```
C:\MyLocation\MyExecutable.exe 4 0 1
```

However because of a requirement to plug into a wider code base, I am now receiving a single argument like so:

```
C:\MyLocation\MyExecutable.exe 401
```

As a result, I now need to break `401` back out into `4 0 1` and can no longer use `m[argv[i]]` directly as previously.

The errors I am now getting in Visual Studio 2017 are:

> Error (active)    E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands SkyQChannelChanger  g:\Visual Studio 2017\C++ Projects\SkyQChannelChanger\SkyQChannelChanger\Main.cpp   147                 operand types are: BasePairMap [ char ]

...and:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2679   binary '[': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    SkyQChannelChanger  g:\visual studio 2017\c++ projects\skyqchannelchanger\skyqchannelchanger\main.cpp   147

I'm only a part time C++ user, but I can tell `argv[i]` is a `char *` and `ii` is an ordinary `char` variable, but I am unsure of two things:

1. Why this matters for a base pair map defined in this way.
2. How (if required) I can define `ii` as a `char *` instead.

Thanks

Comment: [Pro Tip] Use `static_cast<int>(c - '0')` in place of `static_cast<int>(c - 48)`.  Magic numbers should be avoided, or put into named constants.  Actually, `c - '0'` is all you really need since it is already an `int`.

Comment: Why does the map use strings as keys, if you then want to compare them to a number `i`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not 100% sure I am following what you are saying. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @aschepler the idea is to map command line arguments to numerical values that are then converted to binary in the rest of the code I have not posted. Not all keymap values are as above. Others for example are: m["search"] = 10;

Comment: @gdogg371 The number `48` int `static_cast<int>(c - 48)` is the integer value of the ASCII character `'0'`.  ASCII though isn't the only character set that C++ uses and if you happen to be on a platform that uses a particular character set, then `static_cast<int>(c - 48)` will fail to give you the correct result.  `static_cast<int>(c - '0')` on the other hand uses the character literal `'0'`.  No matter what character set the implementation is using, it will convert `'0'` to the correct integer value.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the tip. However, even amending as so does not resolve the main issue I have, which is the lines: int in_arg = m[argv[i]];    //works
                int in_arg = m[ii];         //does not work

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear I wasn't actually trying to fix your problem. I just wanted to point out a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

To create a `std::string` containing just one character `c`, just do

```
std::string(1, c);
```

(More generally, the `string` constructor taking a number `n` and a `char c` results in `n` repetitions of `c`. `std::string(3, 'q')` has the same value as `std::string("qqq")`.)

However, it looks like you don't want to do this to the variable `ii`, which is a number from zero to nine, and not the character representing a decimal digit (which in most encodings are the `char` values from 48 to 57). So you can skip the `vector<int>` and the `(c - 48)` parts, and just do:

```
typedef std::map<string, int> BasePairMap;
BasePairMap m;
// Initialize m...

std::string s1 = argv[1];
for (char c : s1)
    {
        std::string digit_str(1, c);
        int in_arg = m[digit_str];
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: If I add std::cout << in_arg << " "; to the above, from an input of 401 I get an output of 0 0 0

Comment: ...also, as mentioned in the comments, will this code work if for example a base pair map looks like e.g. m["search"] = 10;

Comment: hi - before i can accept the answer, i do not know why i am only getting zero's as my output...

Comment: i really dont follow how std::string digit_str(c, 1) can relate to a base pair map such as mine...the output of std::string digit_str(c, 1) appears to be binary, not a string...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! It has to be `(1, c)`, not `(c, 1)`.